# Get paragraph style in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, styles, jtextpane

I'm doing a text editor using `JTextPane`, I need to add colors to some words but i want that if user clicks on an area that is already colored, to be painted with that color (paragraph style), not logical style. I was looking for `getParagraphAttributes` but I wasn't able to get Paragraph Style as property.

How to get paragraph style in `JTextPane`?

```
private Style getColor(String token) { 
    if (token.equals("while")) 
        return editor.getStyle("blue"); 
    return editor.getLogicalStyle(); //At this point I want current not logical if it's Possible. 
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: private Style getColor(String token) {
    if (token.equals("while"))
    return editor.getStyle("blue");
    return editor.getLogicalStyle(); //At this point I want current not logical if it's possible.
    }

Comment: I can't edit my question, so It's the only way I can show you the SSCCE.

Comment: *"I can't edit my question"*  Why not?  I can.

Comment: Sorry I really don't know what I was thinking (I went to take a nap so...)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
((StyledDocument)textPane.getDocument()).getParagraphElement(position).getAttributes();
```

Comment: I really don't know how get the Style attribute using your code. (I suspect I have to use the getAttribute(Object key) method but my concern is what key to use).

Comment: Just check all the attributes names/values